# Why couldn't the latest version of rsync be installed on CentOS 7.2?

Tags: linux, rsync, centos7

I am using CentOS 7.2.

I would like to install the latest version of rsync - `rsync-3.1.2`,
`rsync-3.0.9` is on system, installed when installing mariadb with `yum`,

```
# rpm -qa |grep rsync
rsync-3.0.9-17.el7.x86_64
```

removing `rsync-3.0.9` first,

```
# yum remove rsync
```

rsync and  mariadb  were removed together,
then,
installing `rsync-3.1.2` from source code,

```
# wget https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/src/rsync-3.1.2.tar.gz
# tar -zxvf rsync-3.1.2.tar.gz
# cd rsync-3.1.2
# ./configure
# make
# make install
```

then,
installing mariadb with `yum` again,
but `rsync-3.0.9` will still be installed.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install rsync 3.1.2 from the Fedora 24 .rpm package:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/24/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/r/rsync-3.1.2-2.fc24.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh rsync-3.1.2-2.fc24.x86_64.rpm
```

(but that question doesn't really belong to stackoverflow)

Comment: You can also pass that url directly to `yum install`.

Answer (score 1):

You can install rsync 3.1.2 from the *gf-plus* repo. Just follow the steps below:

1. Install the `gf-release` package.

   ```
   sudo rpm -Uvh http://mirror.ghettoforge.org/distributions/gf/el/7/gf/x86_64/gf-release-7-10.gf.el7.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Upgrade `rsync` package from the *gf-plus* repo.

   ```
   sudo yum install -y --enablerepo=gf-plus rsync
   ```
3. Check rsync version.

   ```
   hash -r; rsync --version | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}'
   ```

   If it prints `3.1.2`, rsync is upgraded.

By default, only the `gf` repo is enabled, which claims that it "won't overwrite core distro packages". You can disable it:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --disable gf
```

(For `command not found` error, run `sudo yum install -y yum-utils` and try again.)

Or simply remove all the `gf*` repos by removing the `gf-release` package:

```
sudo yum remove -y gf-release
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to install all of your software using packages, or install all of your software from source.  Trying to mix and match is going to lead to exactly the sort of problem you are experiencing here: the `mariadb` package has a dependency on `rsync`, but the package manager doesn't know anything about the files you have installed from source.

The correct way to solve this problem is to build your own `rsync` package that can then be installed with `yum`.  You can start with the source package for your distribution and then modify it for 3.1.2.  You may be able to utilize a more recent package (e.g., from Fedora) and rebuild it for your system.

You can find the source RPM for `rsync-3.0.9` [here](http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/Source/SPackages/rsync-3.0.9-17.el7.src.rpm), and there is some documentation that will hopefully help you get started [here](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM).